# Validation Rule CONTAINS

Tags: validation-rule, roles, contains

**Use Case:** When a NEW Opportunity of a particular RecortType is created, AND the OpportunityOwner Country = 'United States' AND the OpportunityOwner Role has the word 'Sales Manager'  THROW AN ERROR IF the Quantity_Volume__c field is blank

The following validation rule breaks when I add the UserRole.Name

```
        AND (

            ISNEW(),
            ISNULL(Quantity_Volume__c),
            RecordTypeId = '012XxxxxxxxxxxxXXXX',
            CreatedBy.Country = 'United States',
            CONTAINS(CreatedBy.UserRole.Name ,'Sales Manager')      **// Problem here** 
           )
```

What am i missing?

Comment: What's the message if you try to check the syntax? I had no issues copying and pasting this and validating the syntax (replacing Quanitty_Volume__c with my own custom field). Or do you mean it's not throwing an error when you expect it to?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves, Problem is not with validating the syntax. It's not throwing the error when I expect it to when creating a new opportunity. It allows me to successfully create a new Opportunity.

Comment: n.b. - use `ISBLANK` instead of `ISNULL` per SFDC guidelines; use `RecordType.DeveloperName` instead of `RecordTypeId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is `CreatedBy.UserRole.Name` is null when a new opportunity is being created.

Use `$UserRole.Name` instead which has value as its System variable.

So your looks will look like:

```
AND (
    ISNEW(),
    ISNULL(Quantity_Volume__c),
    Record.Developername = 'your developername for record',
    $User.Country = 'United States',
    CONTAINS($UserRole.Name ,'Sales Manager') 
)
```

Comment: I think you meant `Opportunity`, not `Account` - and why not while we're at it `$User.Country`?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Edited above.